# Is there a way to call a function in ListView?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a ListView and I want to execute a script in python to update our database everytime I enter in the listview, or periodically.

Is there a way to do that ?

```
class AccessPointList(generic.ListView): #receives the whole set of AccessPoint and send to HTML
model = AccessPoint
#call a function in python -> c.update()
#or create a def to update our database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just override one of the methods when you want to run it, then call super to continue with normal execution of the ListView

```
class AccessPointList(generic.ListView):
    model = AccessPoint

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call your function
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it seems to work. However now I'm having a problem with the super(). Since I'm using Python 2.7, it is asking to having an argument. This probably some easy stuff, but I'm really a beginner in Django.

Comment: I figure out... we have to call the class, with self

`response = super(AccesPointList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)`

The response is because the get method returns a response to the list.

Comment: Ah, yes, super requires the arguments in python 2. In python3 you can leave it empty